# How to rename the root user in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows

**I did**

- I tried to change the `root@LAPTOP-2NFV79O9:~#` root into the taiga. that's not working. I don't know what's going on

  `1.pkill -u root pid`

  `2.pkill -u root`

  `3.usermod -l taiga root`

**result**

```
usermod: user root is currently used by process 1
```

also, i did `id`

`uid=0(root) gid=0(taiga) groups=0(taiga)`

**My environment**

- windows 10
- ubuntu

**my goal**

- change the user name

Comment: Do you really want to change the name of the root user?

Comment: @thanasisp I want to change the root to the taiga or create the new thing and replace it. is it possible?

Comment: Don't do this (even if it is possible). Follow the link provided for more details.

Comment: might not usually be worth the trouble, but if you're prepared to look for any place that refers to `root` by name and are ready to fix up any issues...